# Rails 4 and ActiveAdmin separated session

Tags: session, ruby-on-rails-4, cookies, activeadmin

I have an app on Ruby on Rails 4. Also using ActiveAdmin and Devise.

Devise store user's info in session. I have 2 models. User and Admin.
Each of them have devise with their own plugins.

Problem: If I logged in as User, and try to login as Admin, Devise store current_client and current_admin in session. Session stores in cookies, e.g. **'_app_session'**. How I can separate cookies and store User's session in **'_app_session'** and Admin's session in **'_app_admin_session'**?

Comment: Please post you routes file, only the devise / active admin related rows.